# google cloud - permission denied when running dynamic inventory through ansible

Tags: ansible, google-cloud-platform

I have followed the Google Cloud Platform Guide for Ansible (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/guide_gce.html) and I can successfully create an instance from a playbook, but when I try to run the ansible commands directly, it gives me a Permission Denied message.

I can run 'gce.py --list' from the inventory directory and it lists all my instances, but when i try to run 'ansible all -i inventory -m setup' it gives me permission denied. I have set the gce.ini correctly and have even set all of the env variables as the guide suggests but no luck. Any ideas? Here is my trace

> jonathan@devopsbox:~/ansible$ ansible all -i inventory -m setup -vvv
>   ansible 2.4.0.0
>   config file = /home/jonathan/ansible/ansible.cfg
>   configured module search path = [u'/home/jonathan/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
>   ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
>   executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
>   python version = 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) [GCC 6.3.0 20170118]
>   Using /home/jonathan/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
>   Parsed /home/jonathan/ansible/inventory/gce.py inventory source with script plugin
>   META: ran handlers
>   Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist packages/ansible/modules/system/setup.py 
>    ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
>    SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s > -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/jonathan/.ansible/cp/3d50765225 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
>    (255, '', 'Permission denied (publickey).\r\n')
>   myinstancename | UNREACHABLE! => {
>      "changed": false, 
>      "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n", 
>      "unreachable": true
>   }

It says user:none. Does that mean it is not passing in my account email/pem_file_path/proj_id? It is set in gce.ini.

I also set in .bashrc the following:
GCE_INI_PATH
GCE_EMAIL
GCE_PROJECT
GCE_CREDENTIALS_FILE

I have tried basically everything but no luck. Running Ansible 2.4 on Ubuntu 17.04:

> ansible --version
>   ansible 2.4.0.0
>    config file = /home/jonathan/ansible/ansible.cfg
>    configured module search path = [u'/home/jonathan/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
>   ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
>   executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
>   python version = 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) [GCC 6.3.0 20170118]

Comment: You have to tell ansible/ssh what credentials file to use (via ssh_config or ssh-agent or group_vars).

Comment: I didn't see anything in the documentation about this. it only mentioned setting the GCE email and credentials file path to the json file. Is this a not documented requirement? Are there any tutorials for setting this up with Google Cloud and dynamic inventory?

Comment: This has nothing in common with GCE or ansible dynamic inventory – it's usual SSH authentication question.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov thanks for the tip. It turns out all i had to do was run gcloud compute ssh... to generate the keys. afterwards everything worked. The ansible documentation could have been more clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the comments:

> You have to tell ansible/ssh what credentials file to use (via ssh_config or ssh-agent or group_vars).

-

> Thanks for the tip. It turns out all i had to do was run `gcloud compute ssh...` to generate the keys. Afterwards everything worked. The Ansible documentation could have been more clear on this.

Comment: Could you be more specific? where should we use the `gcloud compute ssh`?

Answer (score 0):

After spending ages on the issue, I was able to tunnel ansible tasks through gcoud ssh, the solution follows:

create `misc/gssh.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
host="${@: -2: 1}"
cmd="${@: -1: 1}"

socket="/tmp/ansible-ssh-${host}-22-iap"
ZONE=$(gcloud compute instances list --filter="name:${host}" --format='value(zone)')
gcloud_args="
--tunnel-through-iap
--zone=${ZONE}
--quiet
--no-user-output-enabled
--
-C
-o ControlMaster=auto
-o ControlPersist=20
-o PreferredAuthentications=publickey
-o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no
-o PasswordAuthentication=no
-o ConnectTimeout=20"

exec gcloud compute ssh "$host" $gcloud_args -o ControlPath="$socket" "$cmd"
```

also change some settings in `ansible.cfg`

```
[ssh_connection]
pipelining = True
ssh_executable = ./misc/gssh.sh
transfer_method = piped

[defaults]
gathering = False # optional
strategy = free # important
```

also have `gcp.yaml` like:

```
---
plugin: gcp_compute
projects:
  - <PROJECT NAME>
auth_kind: serviceaccount
service_account_file: /opt/ansible/inventory/service-account.json
hostnames:
  - name
compose:
  ansible_host: name
```

Ansible will read the configuration file `ansible.cfg` and will know that it has to tunnel all the commands via gcloud connection created in `gssh.sh`. Hence, any manual ssh key generation and authentication is not required.

Hope this saves someone a bit of research time.

---

EDIT 1:
Zone fetching slows down the process, which can be solved by hardcoding zone in `gssh.sh`; just replace

```
ZONE=$(gcloud compute instances list --filter="name:${host}" --format='value(zone)')
```

by

```
ZONE=<zone name>
```

eg.

```
ZONE="us-central1-a"
```